# My if else statement is not working as intended - innerHTML remaining the same for all statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, innerhtml

I am trying to find out why my conditional statement is not working as intended. The else part of the statement is not working at all, as it remains the same as for the else if statement. I tried to simplify the statement just having an if/else, but it didn't work. I will really appreciate some help to get to the bottom of this issue.

P.S. In my case if I want to use the null statement I must use it as a string. Another mystery.

Here's my code:

```
var name = prompt("Could you please tell me your name?");
    var newP = document.createElement('p');
    newP.setAttribute('id', 'mainP');
    document.body.appendChild(newP);


    if(name == 'null' || '') {
        newP.innerHTML = "I'm just looking for Aname! " + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F612);
    }else if(name == 'Aname' || 'aname') {
        newP.innerHTML = 'Yes, I finally found Aname! ' + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F60D);
    }else {
        newP.innerHTML = "I'm just looking for Aname! " + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F612);
    }
```

Comment: That's not how you should use logical or operator.

Comment: `if (name == 'null' || name == '')` etc

Comment: Please, **please** do not consider "null" a non-name. This causes [great misery](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) for people that actually have that name.

Comment: When you really need to check the `prompt` result for "empty" values, you can do it like this: `if (name && name.trim()) {...}`. A loose check is OK, since `prompt` always returns either `null` or the empty string, or a valid string. `.trim()` check is nice when user enters spaces only.

Answer (score 1):

Your else part is not working at all because your not using `||` operator properly in `if` condition,

> > `Or` operator is used to combine two different logical expressions.

In your case `name == 'null'` and `name == ''` are two different logical expressions.

Actually you just `if..else` that's it. If name is `Aname` or `aname` then execute if block otherwise execute else block

```
   if(name == 'Aname' || name == 'aname') {
                             //^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing
        newP.innerHTML = 'Yes, I finally found Aname! ' + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F60D);
    }else {
        newP.innerHTML = "I'm just looking for Aname! " + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F612);
    }
```

---

Even you don't need two conditions *(It is completely depend on your requirement)*, convert your name to lower case using `toLowerCase()` and check for `aname`, like

```
   //Now this will execute if condition if name is aname, Aname, aName, AName ...    
   if(name.toLowerCase() == 'aname') {
        newP.innerHTML = 'Yes, I finally found Aname! ' + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F60D);
    }else {
        newP.innerHTML = "I'm just looking for Aname! " + String.fromCodePoint(0x1F612);
    }
```

Comment: @Teemu, I updated my answer to support null check, `name == 'null'` will return true if value of name is 'null''

Comment: Why to use logical or at all in empty check? How about ten spaces? Probably not a nice name ...

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a variable to multiple values, you must do so in separate comparisons like the following:

```js
if(name == 'null' || name == ''){

}
```

Currently, your if statement is evaluating the equivalent to the following statement:

```js
if((name == 'null') || ''){

}
```

Comment: Actually, his statement is currently evaluating to something like this `if(Boolean(name == 'null') || Boolean(''))){` and because an empty string in JavaScript is falsy, meaning it evaluates to false, the condition is not met.

Comment: @Linschlager I was just diving into the operator precedence documentation because something felt itchy. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yep, but which order `'null'` respects ..?